# mysql 5.5.42 - locking internally when using "wrong" utf-8 characters in utf-8 varchar column

Tags: mysql

I have very strange behaviour, clearly a bug.

I use utf8_bin as charset for my table.
I now had the case that I tried to insert a string that contains these HEX codes:
"f0 9f 87 a8 f0 9f 87 a6"
That's ""

When I try to update a row with that I get a duplicate key violation. 
But there is no duplicate key.

When I try to DELETE the non-existent row mysql just hangs endless.
I can see the DELETE ... LIMIT1 command in processlist at status "updating".

It's a delete on an indexed row, should take maybe a quarter of a millisecond to finish.
I waited for 20 minutes until I killed it.

Has anyone encountered this error already ?
Is there a way around it ?

--

There is clearly some sort of error in mysql resulting in that weird behaviour, the real issue is my charset.
utf8_bin doesn't support 4 chars.

IF someone runs into a similar issue, this might be helpful:

```
([\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3})
```

That's the regex code required to match 4 byte UTF8 characters.
You can modify them, encode them or replace them.

Comment: It seems mysql doesn't support 4 byte unicodes, only 3 byte.
I guess utf8mb4 would solve my issue, but I can't recreate my table anymore. too large.

However, this does not explain why mysql internally hangs when using 4 byte codes.